# Why am I getting "cannot find module" I've already tried everything

Tags: node.js

Every time I run node server.js this shows up. I've already tried installing and reinstalling new things but that doesn't work.

> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/projects/node-express-server/server.json'
>
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
>   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
>   at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
>   Users-MBP-3:node101-express-server user$

Comment: What's the difference between the working directory you're launching node from, `node101-express-server`, and the directory `node-express-server`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/projects/node-express-server/server.json'
```

should be server.js not server.json

Comment: @junior, please mark this as answer if it resolved your issue. This was the first response to the question

Answer (score 0):

To run node app, you have to call it's server file not json file.

In your case , you have `server.js` file and you tried to call `server.json` file.

To prevent this type of mistake, install `sudo npm install nodemon -g`

Then  just simple run `nodemon`, It will automatically use app/server file.